# How to schedule a eclipse java program to run daily at 8 PM?

Tags: java

Can anyone please help me in scheduling to run a eclipse java program daily at 8 PM?

I used various methods such as codepro, quartz but i don't know how it works?

Comment: A quartz is a easy/simple scheduler...why wouldn't it work

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7855666/cron-job-for-a-java-program theres already solution here better check stackoverflow before you post .

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
    public void run() {
        // what to do every 8:00am
    }
}, new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss").parse("2016-2-23 8:00:00"), 24*60*60*1000);
```

**Explain:**

Start time: `new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss").parse("2016-2-23 8:00:00");`

Period after first start: `24*60*60*1000` = one day in milliseconds.