# Is there a way to run a jar at scheduled times using IBM websphere

Tags: java, tomcat

I have created a stand alone jar which does some job. The job has to be run at scheduled time regularly. I can invoke the jar using windows schedular. But I want to know if I can use tomcat or IBM web sphere server to invoke the jar at scheduled times.

Of course I can create a war file and deploy it in server but that is not what I am looking for.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cron job for a Java Program](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7855666/cron-job-for-a-java-program)

Answer (score 0):

Many ways but WAS specific asked so will suggest to use cron job feature.

Go to WAS Console > Resources > Schedulers. To implement a CRON like calendar set the UserCalendar on the TaskInfo object, sample:

```
taskInfo.setUserCalendar(null, "CRON");
taskInfo.setStartTimeInterval("* 10 * * ?")
```

Read more [here](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_7.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/info/ae/ae/welc6tech_sch_adm.html) in docs.

Comment: Thank you for your reply Sheetal. When I went through the link, I have found that only on J2EE  applications, the default scheduler calendars will work. However what I want is, I have independent jar file and I want to invoke that jar from IBM web sphere. ..

Comment: Write a shell script..simple?

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware if tomcat/websphere provides explicit support to handle your issue. Since you have mentioned multiple app servers, I suggest to go for simple java's timer packaged inside your jar, an example listed [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/timer_schedule_period.htm)

This approach will give you app server independence as well as OS independence. You can for cron4J or quartz if your requirements grow.