# How to execute a query interval of 1 month in mysql

Tags: java, mysql

I am developing an application using servlet and jdbc using mysql database.

Here I have to move one table data into other table in every month end(**lets say 30th**)

**visitorlog**

id       name    date

1       XYZ     02-10-2016

**visitorloghistory**

id    name    date

Here I have to move all data of visitorlog into visitorloghistory in each month end, and need to remove data from visitorlog.

I have no idea how to do this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is called event scheduler or more specifically cron job. The following should help you to start:

https://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-create-mysql-events/

http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-triggers/working-mysql-scheduled-event/

The event schedulers are set to perform specific tasks depending upon time. The following is a sample:

```
DELIMITER ;;
  CREATE EVENT UpdateData ON SCHEDULE EVERY DAY STARTS '2016-10-10 00:00:00' -- This is scheduled to start from '2016-10-10' and updates data every day
  DO BEGIN
    UPDATE table1 SET Status = 1 WHERE Status = 0;
    UPDATE table2 SET Status = 1 WHERE Status = 0;
  END;;
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Where i have to write such query in some batch file or in servlet program.

Comment: This should be done in the MySQL server.

Answer (score 0):

Your can check this out. Write a script which will run at particular time.

[Cron job for a Java Program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7855666/cron-job-for-a-java-program][1])